# What version of thinking-sphinx gem to use on Lion, Rails 2.3.9, sphinx 0.9.9 and Ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: osx-lion, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

The error I'm getting with the thinking-sphinx 2.1.0 gem is:

```
Sphinx cannot be found on your system. You may need to configure the following
settings in your config/sphinx.yml file:
* bin_path
* searchd_binary_name
* indexer_binary_name

sh: searchd: command not found
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /var/log/searchd.log.
Failed to start searchd daemon. Check /var/log/searchd.log
Be sure to run thinking_sphinx:index before thinking_sphinx:start
```

Search log is empty

and when I try to manually run rake task from bash I get:

```
rake aborted!
Unable to activate thinking-sphinx-2.0.10, because activerecord-2.3.9 conflicts with   activerecord (>= 3.0.3)
```

activerecord 3.0.3 downloaded with the thinking-sphinx gem 2.0.9 automatically.

I have tried almost every version of thinking sphinx and sphinx and just get various errors with every attempt.

Sphinx runs great from a bash command line, but no go from the rake tasks. I have tried the plugin, but that just throws a different set of errors. I am hoping someone knows of a combination of rails / riddle / thinking-sphinx and or sphinx versions on mac lion, if mac version even matters.

And my current conf is as follows:

```
development:
bin_path: /usr/local/Cellar/sphinx/0.9.9/bin
searchd_binary_name: searchd
indexer_binary_name: indexer
enable_star: true
enable_star: true
morphology: stem_en
html_strip: true
min_infix_len: 3
port: 9310
sql_range_step: 10000000
min_infix_len: 3
```

Thanks much in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered this on the mailing list as well, but just for others who come across it - 1.4.10 is the right version of TS to use (the 2.x releases of Thinking Sphinx are for Rails 3.x).